# What does the following do

Tags: java

What do these do? I cant find them in my textbook?

```
Double number = new Double(8.8);
Float number = new Float(8.8);
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Comment: @Erik, Java 1.4.2? Geez, upgrade buddy! :)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: First google hit :P

Comment: Neither Double nor Float have changed significantly since 1.4.2.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code are instantiating two new objects, one of type `Double` and one of type `Float`.  (Note that these are different than the primitive types `double` and `float`.  They basically wrap the primitive types in objects.)  They're doing so by calling the constructor for each of these types and passing them numeric values with which to instantiate them.

See [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double%28double%29) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float%28double%29).

Answer (score 1):

Each line declares a new variable named "number" and assigns it a new object of the declared type.  Double for the first line, Float for the second.

Comment: Finally, you saw what others didn't.

Answer (score 0):

The Java programming language provides two built-in classes for representing floating-point numbers: float, and double. The "`Float`" class takes 4 bytes of storage, and have *23 binary digits of precision*. The "`Double`" class takes 8 bytes of storage, and have *52 binary digits of precision*.

In your example, you create one-of-each, but they have different digits of precision.

Comment: `float` and `double` are no classes in Java, but primitive types. `Float` and `Double` are their wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates a double precision Object of a floating point number, the second one a single precision Object of a floating point number.

Answer (score 0):

They are called [Wrapper](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html) classes. They are wrapper for primitive data types.